# dplyr NSE mode in a function: nested conditions

Tags: r, function, dplyr, nse

The objective is to transform column(s) of a data frame. Here is the example:

```
  df <- data.frame( fact=c("dog",2,"NA",0,"cat",1,"Cat"),
              value=c(4,2,6,0,9,1,3) ); df$fact <- as.factor(df$fac)

  func <- function(data,fac,val){
          data <- data %>%  
          mutate_(fac= interp(~tolower(fac), fac=as.name(fac)) ) %>%
          mutate_(val= interp(~ifelse(fac=='cat',1*val,
                       ifelse(fac=='dog',2*val,0)), fac=as.name(fac), val=as.name(val)))
  return(data) }
```

The call:

```
new.df <- func(df,"fact","value")

     fact value  fac val
   1  dog     4  dog  8
   2    2     2   2   0
   3   NA     6  na   0
   4    0     0   0   0
   5  cat     9 cat   9
   6    1     1   1   0
   7  Cat     3 cat   0
```

presents 2 issues: (1)- the value associated to "Cat" is false; should be 3*1=3
                   (2)- the call ideally returns the original data.frame `df` with the transformed `fact` and `value` variables.

Any thoughts? Thank you guys.

**Edit**: please note that `df` has another column `third` which should be left unaffected by the operations done to `fact` and `value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return the *original* columns (potentially including other columns in your data.frame) with the original names, you can use a slightly different dplyr-approach with `mutate_each` instead of `mutate`:

```
library(lazyeval)
library(dplyr)

func <- function(data,fac,val) {
  data %>%  
    mutate_each_(interp(~tolower(var), var = as.name(fac)), fac) %>% 
    mutate_each_(interp(~ifelse(col =='cat', var, ifelse(col == 'dog',2*var, 0)), 
             var=as.name(val), col = as.name(fac)), val)
}
```

Using the function:

```
func(df, "fact", "value")
#  fact value
#1  dog     8
#2    2     0
#3   na     0
#4    0     0
#5  cat     9
#6    1     0
#7  cat     3
```

The difference to akruns answer is demonstrated if you have other columns in your data that you like to keep in it (whereas they would be removed with akrun's approach because of the `transmute`):

```
df$some_column <- letters[1:7]  # add a new column
```

Other columns now remain in your data after using the function and the modified columns keep their original names:

```
func(df, "fact", "value")
#  fact value some_column
#1  dog     8           a
#2    2     0           b
#3   na     0           c
#4    0     0           d
#5  cat     9           e
#6    1     0           f
#7  cat     3           g
```

Comment: @@docendo: I realize akrun solution presents one issue, I haven't mentioned in the question: `df` has other columns (ie variables) which should remain unaffected after the transformations done to `fact` and `value`. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: @remi, have you tried using the function in my answer? It does exactly that.

Comment: @@docendo: indeed, your solution resolved the issue before I became aware of it! I got another worry :-\ : handling the NA's, given the `tolower` operation. Should one include: `na.omit()` to resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

In the OP's code, the 'val' was created based on the unmodified 'fact' column.  If we are using the modified 'fac' from the first `mutate_`, we don't need `as.name(fac)`.

```
library(lazyeval)
library(dplyr)
func <- function(data,fac,val){
      data <- data %>%  
               mutate_(fac= interp(~tolower(fac), fac=as.name(fac))) %>%
               mutate_(val= interp(~ifelse(fac=='cat',1*val,
                   ifelse(fac=='dog',2*val,0)), val=as.name(val)))
  return(data) } 

func(df, 'fact', 'value')
#  fact value fac val
#1  dog     4 dog   8
#2    2     2   2   0
#3   NA     6  na   0
#4    0     0   0   0
#5  cat     9 cat   9
#6    1     1   1   0
#7  Cat     3 cat   3
```

If we need to return only the modified columns, use `transmute_`

```
func1 <- function(data,fac,val){
      data <- data %>%  
               transmute_(fac= interp(~tolower(fac), fac=as.name(fac)), 
                      val= interp(~ifelse(fac=='cat',1*val,
                         ifelse(fac=='dog',2*val,0)), val=as.name(val)))
     return(data) } 

func1(df, 'fact', 'value')
#  fac val
#1 dog   8
#2   2   0
#3  na   0
#4   0   0
#5 cat   9
#6   1   0
#7 cat   3
```

Comment: @@akrun: thanks so much, didn't know about `transmute`.